# Full match against a List of strings per id

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I need a Linq query that will return null if not all the rows have matching string from within a `List<string>` for each hardware_id column.

I have the following table:

- id (int) - Primary Key
- name (string)
- user_id (int)
- hardware_id (int)

I have a `List<string>` that contain phrases. I want the query to return the hardare_id number if all the phrases in the List have matching strings in the name row. If there one of the phrases doesn't have a `name` match, to return null and if all the phrases exist per each hardware_id for all the phrases, the query should return the list of hardware_id's that each one of those hardware_id's, have full match with all the phrases within the List.

Or in other words, return a list of `hardware_id`'s that each id, has its all `name` 's matching the ones in the `List<string>`.

I thought about iterating each Id in a different query but it's not an effective way to do it. Maybe you know a good query to tackle this.
I'm using Entity Framework 6 / C# / MySQL

Note: the query is done only per user id. So I filter the table first by the User Id and then need to find the matching hardare_id's that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Group on `hardware_id` and then look for all phrases existence in the `List`

```
table.GroupBy(x=>x.hardware_id)
     .Where(x=> x.All(s=> phrases.Contains(s.name))
     .Select(x=>x.Key);
```

Comment: I will try it out now, I was close, I start with group by on the hardware_id and I thought iterating over it with for each, but yours looks like a slick query-only solution.

Comment: Where do I add the user_id filtering? I need to add another filter to the Where section.

Comment: I would suggest place it in `Where` condition itself.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add a second condition in the WHERE. should I add another .WHERE before the first one. I need to filter the data before I run the query, so it will only run for a specifc user_id. It doesn't allow me to chain two wHERE conditions.

Comment: I have a problem with the code. When I have one tag in the List of hardware_id to search by and there is a row that matches hardware_id, it returns no results. If there is one match, I still want to return matching results, just there is tag that together doesn't have a match, return no results. In other words, if there is one tag that doesn't match for a particular hardware_id, return no results.